# Daily Inventory from Bought/Sold transaction log

Tags: mysql, transactions, inventory

The following SQL queries describe two tables and their contents, a small and simplified part of a big inventory system.

The first is a transaction log listing bought and sold quantities of various items.

```
CREATE TABLE `Inventar_actions` (
  `PartID` char(8) NOT NULL,
  `DateSeq` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ActionType` enum('Bought','Sold') NOT NULL,
  `Units` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`PartID`,`DateSeq`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `test`.`Inventar_actions` (`PartID`, `DateSeq`, `ActionType`, `Units`) VALUES 
('0001', '1020', 'Bought', '100'),('0001', '1025', 'Sold', '20'),('0001', '1028', 'Sold', '30'),
('0001', '1031', 'Bought', '100'),('0001', '1035', 'Sold', '50');
```

The second table is a calendar, listing business days and their sequential numbers from an arbitrary epoch:

```
CREATE TABLE `BusinessDates` (
  `DateSeq` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `BusinessDate` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DateSeq`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `test`.`BusinessDates` (`DateSeq`, `BusinessDate`) VALUES 
('1015', '2020-02-03'),('1016', '2020-02-04'),('1017', '2020-02-05'),('1018', '2020-02-06'),('1019', '2020-02-07'),
('1020', '2020-02-10'),('1021', '2020-02-11'),('1022', '2020-02-12'),('1023', '2020-02-13'),('1024', '2020-02-14'),
('1025', '2020-02-17'),('1026', '2020-02-18'),('1027', '2020-02-19'),('1028', '2020-02-20'),('1029', '2020-02-21'),
('1030', '2020-02-24'),('1031', '2020-02-25'),('1032', '2020-02-26'),('1033', '2020-02-27'),('1034', '2020-02-28'),
('1035', '2020-03-02'),('1036', '2020-03-03'),('1037', '2020-03-04'),('1038', '2020-03-05'),('1039', '2020-03-06')
;
```

What I need is a daily inventory, one that looks something like this:

```
| 1020 | 2020-02-10 | 100 | Bought | 100 |
| 1021 | 2020-02-11 |     |        | 100 |
| 1022 | 2020-02-12 |     |        | 100 |
| 1023 | 2020-02-13 |     |        | 100 |
| 1024 | 2020-02-14 |     |        | 100 |
| 1025 | 2020-02-17 |  20 | Sold   |  80 |
| 1026 | 2020-02-18 |     |        |  80 |
| 1027 | 2020-02-19 |     |        |  80 |
| 1028 | 2020-02-20 |  30 | Sold   |  50 |
| 1029 | 2020-02-21 |     |        |  50 |
| 1030 | 2020-02-24 |     |        |  50 |
| 1031 | 2020-02-25 | 100 | Bought | 150 |
| 1032 | 2020-02-26 |     |        | 150 |
| 1033 | 2020-02-27 |     |        | 150 |
| 1034 | 2020-02-28 |     |        | 150 |
| 1035 | 2020-03-02 |  50 | Sold   | 100 |
| 1036 | 2020-03-03 |     |        | 100 |
| 1037 | 2020-03-04 |     |        | 100 |
| 1038 | 2020-03-05 |     |        | 100 |
| 1039 | 2020-03-06 |     |        | 100 |
```

That is, for each business date what is the balance of each PartID, given parts bought and sold.

I used the following query to line up dates, date-sequence and transactions:

```
SELECT d.DateSeq, d.BusinessDate, a.`Units`, a.`ActionType` 
FROM `BusinessDates` AS d LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT DateSeq, ActionType, Units FROM `Inventar_actions` WHERE PartID = '0001') AS a USING (DateSeq)
WHERE d.DateSeq BETWEEN 1020 AND 1039
ORDER BY d.DateSeq;
```

This produces the first four columns of the desired output.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a query that will also produce the last column, the balance inventory of parts.

Please note that there are *a lot* of PartID's and thousands of business days.

Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works with mysql 5.x and 8.0

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `Inventar_actions` (
>   `PartID` char(8) NOT NULL,
>   `DateSeq` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
>   `ActionType` enum('Bought','Sold') NOT NULL,
>   `Units` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`PartID`,`DateSeq`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
>
> INSERT INTO `Inventar_actions` (`PartID`, `DateSeq`, `ActionType`, `Units`) VALUES 
> ('0001', '1020', 'Bought', '100'),('0001', '1025', 'Sold', '20'),('0001', '1028', 'Sold', '30'),
> ('0001', '1031', 'Bought', '100'),('0001', '1035', 'Sold', '50');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE `BusinessDates` (
>   `DateSeq` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
>   `BusinessDate` date NOT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`DateSeq`)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
>
> INSERT INTO `BusinessDates` (`DateSeq`, `BusinessDate`) VALUES 
> ('1015', '2020-02-03'),('1016', '2020-02-04'),('1017', '2020-02-05'),('1018', '2020-02-06'),('1019', '2020-02-07'),
> ('1020', '2020-02-10'),('1021', '2020-02-11'),('1022', '2020-02-12'),('1023', '2020-02-13'),('1024', '2020-02-14'),
> ('1025', '2020-02-17'),('1026', '2020-02-18'),('1027', '2020-02-19'),('1028', '2020-02-20'),('1029', '2020-02-21'),
> ('1030', '2020-02-24'),('1031', '2020-02-25'),('1032', '2020-02-26'),('1033', '2020-02-27'),('1034', '2020-02-28'),
> ('1035', '2020-03-02'),('1036', '2020-03-03'),('1037', '2020-03-04'),('1038', '2020-03-05'),('1039', '2020-03-06')
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>    d.DateSeq
>    , d.BusinessDate
>    , a.`Units`
>    , a.`ActionType`
>       , 
>    CASE 
>      WHEN a.`ActionType` = 'Bought' THEN @inventory := @inventory + a.`Units`
>    WHEN a.`ActionType` = 'Sold' THEN @inventory := @inventory - a.`Units`
>    ELSE
>     @inventory := @inventory
>    END inventory
> FROM (SELECT * FROM `BusinessDates` ORDER BY  BusinessDate ASC) AS d LEFT JOIN 
> (SELECT DateSeq, ActionType, Units FROM `Inventar_actions` WHERE PartID = '0001') AS a USING (DateSeq)
> ,(SELECT @inventory := 0) b
> WHERE d.DateSeq BETWEEN 1020 AND 1039
> ORDER BY d.DateSeq;
> ```
>
> ```
> DateSeq | BusinessDate | Units | ActionType | inventory
> ------: | :----------- | ----: | :--------- | :--------
>    1020 | 2020-02-10   |   100 | Bought     | 100      
>    1021 | 2020-02-11   |  null | null       | 100      
>    1022 | 2020-02-12   |  null | null       | 100      
>    1023 | 2020-02-13   |  null | null       | 100      
>    1024 | 2020-02-14   |  null | null       | 100      
>    1025 | 2020-02-17   |    20 | Sold       | 80       
>    1026 | 2020-02-18   |  null | null       | 80       
>    1027 | 2020-02-19   |  null | null       | 80       
>    1028 | 2020-02-20   |    30 | Sold       | 50       
>    1029 | 2020-02-21   |  null | null       | 50       
>    1030 | 2020-02-24   |  null | null       | 50       
>    1031 | 2020-02-25   |   100 | Bought     | 150      
>    1032 | 2020-02-26   |  null | null       | 150      
>    1033 | 2020-02-27   |  null | null       | 150      
>    1034 | 2020-02-28   |  null | null       | 150      
>    1035 | 2020-03-02   |    50 | Sold       | 100      
>    1036 | 2020-03-03   |  null | null       | 100      
>    1037 | 2020-03-04   |  null | null       | 100      
>    1038 | 2020-03-05   |  null | null       | 100      
>    1039 | 2020-03-06   |  null | null       | 100
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cbd382023642b58af856519bda936cb6)*